# Excel graph hide data label if = #N/A

Tags: excel, graph

In Excel, I am generating a bar chart from cells using the N/A() function (=IF(value=0,NA(),value)).
**I precise I cannot use "" instead of n/a() and I must use bar graphs.**

My problem is I cannot prevent data labels from showing #N/A for N/A cells...

I tried many formats for the data label, using this definition:
**positive;negative;zero;text**.
For example this one:  **0;-0;;**

It prevents well any text, or 0 value to be displayed in data labels... But #N/A remains.

[image]

I have read many topics on various forums and sites without success.
Could you please help on this ?

Answer (score -1):

You can filter the columns in your data series by right clicking on the column and navigating to the "Select Data" option. From there you can un-check the data from the horizontal axis that you don't want to be displayed.

Comment: But this is dynamic. 
I don't want to manually unselect N/A cells for each time my worksheet computes something new.
I am looking for something more dynamic, that automatically hides data label if = #N/A.